# A stronger notion of injectivity

Tags: set-theory

An injective map between two sets of the same cardinality is bijective if at least one of the sets is finite. This is not true if we drop the assumption that at least one of the sets is finite. Is there a strengthening of the notion of injectivity such that the statement continues to hold?

Comment: Though not related, but there is a notion of size which obeys Aristotle's principle (that sets have more elements than their proper subsets have). May look at "Numerosities of labelled sets: a new way of counting", and "An Aristotelian notion of size" and "An Euclidean Measure of Size for Mathematical Universes".

Comment: A linear linjection of vector spaces is bijective if at least one of them is finite-dimensional.

Comment: you probably mean something different, consider the inclusion of the zero into the line. Either that their dimensions are equal as cardinals, or your coefficient field is finite (so you can compare the cardinalities of the vector spaces themselves).

Comment: Every infinite structure has a proper elementary extension. So there is no first-order structure-dependent notion which strengthens injectivity and entails surjectivity for infinite sets.

Comment: Under ZF, there's the notion of Dedekind-finite set (under ZF+DC it means finite).

Comment: For maps preserving some particular structure there are plenty of examples, see "co-hopfian".

Comment: Since on the one hand the question is little focussed and in some more precise forms has already been discussed, and on the other hand the OP has closed their account, I'm voting to closed the question.

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ and $B$ are countable and equipped with probability measures $\mu_A$, $\mu_B$ that give each element positive probability then any measure-preserving map is a bijection. (I guess per @MonroeEskew's comment this is not first order).